# c# How to find if two objects are equal

Tags: c#, comparison, hash

I want to know the best way to compare two objects and to find out if they're equal. I'm overriding both GethashCode and Equals. So a basic class looks like:

```
public class Test
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string String1 { get; set; }
    public string String2 { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Value ^ String1.GetHashCode() ^ String2.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals( object obj )
    {
        return GetHashCode() == obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

So for testing purposes I created two objects:

```
Test t = new Test()
{
    Value = 1,
    String1 ="One",
    String2 = "One"
};

Test t2 = new Test()
{
    Value = 1,
    String1 = "Two",
    String2 = "Two"
};

bool areEqual = t.Equals( t2 );
```

In testing this areEqual returns true event though both objects are different. I realise this is because String1 and String2 are the same value in each object and thus cancels each other out when hashing.

Is there a better way off hashing object that the method I have that will resolve my issue?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Your current equality method is broken - there are more values than possible hash codes. It's entirely reasonable (and expected) that you will occasionally have values which are unequal but give the same hash. Equals should check the *actual values*:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    Test test = obj as Test;
    if (obj == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return Value == test.Value &&
        String1 == test.String1 &&
        String2 == test.String2;
}
```

A few things to note:

- Your way of generating the hashcode will give the same value for any fixed `Value` if `String1` and `String2` are the same; it will also blow up if `String1` or `String2` is null. This is an unfortunate aspect of using XOR for hashing. I prefer something like this:

  ```
  // Put this extension method in a utility class somewhere
  public static int SafeGetHashCode<T>(this T value) where T : class
  {
      return value == null ? 0 : value.GetHashCode();
  }

  // and this in your actual class
  public override int GetHashCode()
  {
      int hash = 19;
      hash = hash * 31 + Value;
      hash = hash * 31 + String1.SafeGetHashCode();
      hash = hash * 31 + String2.SafeGetHashCode();
      return hash;
  }
  ```
- Generally speaking, equality becomes tricky when inheritance gets involved. You may want to consider sealing your class.
- You may also want to implement `IEquatable<Test>`

Comment: Re `SafeGetHashCode` - just to mention that `EqualityComparer<T>.GetHashCode` will do something very similar - the extension method is quite tidy, though ;p

Comment: Your answer is really good, whereas the first word is wrong: "No" is the wrong answer to his question:
"Is there a better way ..."
Moreover Simons Test class does not have a base class nor does it implement a interface. so the override keyword is really wrong

Comment: @Oops: Will fix the "No"... but the Test class *does* have a base class - the implicit base class of System.Object. These methods *are* overriding the Object implementations.

Answer (score 17):

Your `Equals` is incorrect - that should **define** what it means for two things to be equal - and having the same hash-code does **not** mean equality (however; a different hash-code **does** mean non-equality). If "equality" means "both strings are pairwise equal", then **test** that.

Re a better hash; xor is notorious for this, since it is trivial to get 0 by xor a value with itself. A better approach may be something like:

```
int i = 0x65407627;
i = (i * -1521134295) + Value.GetHashCode();
i = (i * -1521134295) + (String1 == null ? 0 : String1.GetHashCode());
i = (i * -1521134295) + (String2 == null ? 0 : String2.GetHashCode());
return i;
```

Comment: (updated, borrowing the seed and multiplier that the C# compiler uses for anonymous types)

Comment: Why did you choose those values for generating the hash code?

Comment: @Carlos: See Marc's previous comment :)

Comment: @Jon: I've seen if before, but I haven't understood. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: @Carlos - I honestly don't know why MS chose those ones *specifically* - the seed+factor approach is common enough, though. The values can be pretty much anything that gives a decent scatter (and the -ve may help with that)

Answer (score 7):

simple

```
Object.Equals(obj1, obj2);
```

Comment: This all depends on whether obj1/obj2 are reference types or not. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx

Comment: This is actually the best answer, it's the briefest, clearest and 100% correct.

Answer (score 2):

For any two objects, object equality implies hash code equality, *however*, hash code equality does not imply object equality.  From [`Object.GetHashCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) on MSDN:

> A hash function must have the
>   following properties:
>
> If two objects compare as equal, the
>   GetHashCode method for each object
>   must return the same value. However,
>   if two objects do not compare as
>   equal, the GetHashCode methods for the
>   two object do not have to return
>   different values.

In other words, your `Equals` is written wrong.  It should be something like:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    Test other = obj as Test;
    if (other == null)
        return false;

    return (Value == other.Value)
        && (String1 == other.String1)
        && (String2 == other.String2);
}
```

`GetHashCode` is good for collections (like `Dictionary<K, V>`) to quickly determine approximate equality.  `Equals` is for comparing if two objects really are the same.

Answer (score 2):

You could serialise the two objects to JSON, then compare the two strings to see if they are the same.

For example

```
JavaSriptSerializer serialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();

string t1String = serialiser.Serialize(t);
string t2String = serialiser.Serialize(t2);

if(t1String == t2String)
   return true; //they are equal
else
   return false;
```

Comment: it doesn't always work. JSON has its own limitation. Depending on JSON to compare general object is not a good idea.

Comment: Tried this and it doesn't work. It causes false negatives due to the different ordering of properties in the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't a function Equals always test only against the same type, shouldn't it be:

```
//override
    public bool Equals(Test other)//(object obj) 
    {
        //return GetHashCode() == obj.GetHashCode();
        return (Value == other.Value) &&
               (String1 == other.String1) &&
               (String2 == other.String2);
    }
```

regards
Oops

Comment: You *should* override the method from Object. You could *also* implement `IEquatable<Test>`, which is when you'd specify this signature.

Comment: hmm don't know, is it an issue of the VS2010 beta? If I use override here, VS says: 'Test.Equals(Test)': no suitable method found to override