# Are custom objects equal by value with List<>

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following classes:

```
 public class MyDocuments
    {
        public DateTime registeredDate;
        public string version;
        public List<Document> registeredDocuments;
    }

    public class Document
    {
        public string name;
        public List<File> registeredFiles;
    }

    public class File
    {
        public string name;
        public string content;
    }
```

I have an instance of MyDocuments which has several documents in `List<Document> registeredDocument`. I get a new `List<Document>` from the user.

How can I verify that  the new object doesn't exist in the list? I want to compare by value not reference.

I'm thinking of using HashSet instead of List. Is this the proper approach?

Comment: If it's your own object, then you need your own definition of equality.

Comment: Implement IEquatable and/or IComparable for each object you want tested for equality.  see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx

Comment: In your example, what is your [natural key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_key)? And [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How are equality comparisons performed?

Whenever the BCL classes want to perform an equality check between objects of some type `T`, they do so by calling one or both of the methods in some implementation of [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.iequalitycomparer.aspx). To get hold of such an implementation, the framework looks to [`EqualityComparer<T>.Default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763.aspx).

As mentioned in the documentation, this property produces an `IEqualityComparer<T>` like this:

> The `Default property` checks whether type T implements the
>   `System.IEquatable<T>` interface and, if so, returns an
>   `EqualityComparer<T>` that uses that implementation. Otherwise, it
>   returns an `EqualityComparer<T>` that uses the overrides of
>   `Object.Equals` and `Object.GetHashCode` provided by `T`.

#### What are my options?

So, in general, to dictate how equality comparisons should be performed you can:

1. Explicitly provide an implementation of `IEqualityComparer<T>` to the class or method that performs equality checks. This option is not very visible with `List<T>`, but many LINQ methods (such as [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118.aspx)) do support it.
2. Make your class implement `IEquatable<T>`. This will make `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` use this implementation, and is a good choice whenever there is an obvious "natural" way to compare objects of type `T`.
3. Override `object.GetHashCode` and `object.Equals` without implementing `IEqualityComparer<T>`. However, this is simply an inferior version of #2 and AFAIK should always be avoided.

#### Which option to pick?

A good rule of thumb is: if there is an obvious and natural way to compare objects of class `T`, consider having it implement `IEquatable<T>`; this will make sure your comparison logic is used throughout the framework without any additional involvement. If there is no obvious candidate, or if you want to compare in a manner different than the default, implement your own `IEqualityComparer<T>` and pass the implementation as an argument to the class or method that needs to perform equality checks.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to implement the `Equals()` method, and probably `GetHashCode()` as well.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2920408/298754) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement [`IEquatable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx).

When you implement this interface on your custom object, any equality checks (e.g. Contains, IndexOf) are automatically done using your objects implementation.

Answer (score 0):

override the [object.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx) method.

here's an example straight from the documentation

```
public class Person
{
   private string idNumber;
   private string personName;

   public Person(string name, string id)
   {
      this.personName = name;
      this.idNumber = id;
   }

   public override bool Equals(Object obj)
   {
      Person personObj = obj as Person; 
      if (personObj == null)
         return false;
      else 
         return idNumber.Equals(personObj.idNumber);
   }

   public override int GetHashCode()
   {
      return this.idNumber.GetHashCode(); 
   }
}
```

the `Equals` method returns a bool which is whether or not `obj` is equal to `this`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this at the top level, continued down at the sub-levels:

```
public class MyDocuments
{
    public DateTime registeredDate;
    public string version;
    public HashSet<Document> registeredDocuments;
    public override bool Equals(Object o)
    {
        if( !(o is MyDocuments) ) return false;
        MyDocuments that = (MyDocuments)o;
        if( !String.Equals(this.version, that.version) ) return false;
        if( this.registeredDocuments.Count != that.registeredDocuments.Count ) return false;
        // assuming registeredDate doesn't matter for equality...
        foreach( Document d in this.registeredDocuments )
            if( !that.registeredDocuments.Contains(d) )
                return false;
        return true;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int ret = version.GetHashCode();
        foreach (Document d in this.registeredDocuments)
            ret ^= d.GetHashCode(); // xor isn't great, but better than nothing.
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Note: Caching could be useful for the HashCode values if the properties were change-aware.