# C# Nuget or AutoCode Generator to Compare Multiple Objects in Unit Testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, nunit, asp.net-core-2.0

The following test creates error when I test tuples.

> 'Assert.AreEqual(test,productRepository.GetById(1))' threw an exception of type 'NUnit.Framework.AssertionException'

Many  solutions presented below require an override equals function for each model. This is very hard to maintain for software with 200+ models in project. Is there any Nuget package or auto code generator which will create equality override methods for all the 200 models?

These all ask to override

- [How to Compare two objects in unit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046121/how-to-compare-two-objects-in-unit-test)
- [C# - Asserting two objects are equal in unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23530982/c-sharp-asserting-two-objects-are-equal-in-unit-tests)
- [c# How to find if two objects are equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920399/c-sharp-how-to-find-if-two-objects-are-equal)

**NUnit Test**

```
[Test]
public void TestProducts()
{
    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ElectronicsContext>()
        .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "Products Test")
        .Options;

    using (var context = new ElectronicsContext(options))
    {
        //DbContextOptionsBuilder<ElectronicsContext> context = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ElectronicsContext>()

        context.Product.Add(new Product { ProductId = 1, ProductName = "TV", ProductDescription = "TV testing", ImageLocation = "test" });
        context.SaveChanges();
        ProductRepository productRepository = new ProductRepository(context);
        var test = new Product
            {ProductId = 1, ProductName = "TV", ProductDescription = "TV testing", ImageLocation = "test"};

       **//This works**
        Assert.AreEqual("TV", productRepository.GetById(1).ProductName);

       **//This Fails**
        Assert.AreEqual(test,productRepository.GetById(1));

       **//This Fails**
        Assert.AreEqual(Object.Equals(test, productRepository.GetById(1)), 1);
    }
```

**Repository**

```
public class ProductRepository : IProductRepository<Product>
{
    private readonly ElectronicsContext _context;
    public ProductRepository(ElectronicsContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProduct()
    {
        return _context.Product.ToList();
    }

    public IQueryable<Product> Products => _context.Product;

    public Product GetById(int productid)
    {
        return _context.Product.Find(productid);

    }
}
```

**Model**

```
public partial class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
    public string ImageLocation { get; set; }

    public int? ProductCategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductCategory ProductCategory { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be checking the Id of the object returned.  Trying to test that the classes are the same will fail if the reference pointers aren't equal.  Since the framework can use proxies, this will not always be true.

Answer (score 0):

Try [FluentAssertions](https://fluentassertions.com/documentation/) nuget package (see section "[Object graph comparison](https://fluentassertions.com/documentation/#object-graph-comparison)").

Instead of

```
Assert.AreEqual(test,productRepository.GetById(1))
```

You can do something like:

```
test.Should().BeEquivalentTo(productRepository.GetById(1));
```